# How to get the calling process name in Custom Claims Provider

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to find the process which is calling the claim provider?. I have a typical scenario in my application where I need to changed the logic if the claim provider is invoked from the workflow. I have tried keeping the SPContext null check, but there are other places where this condition fails. So looking for the possibility of getting the name of the calling process in the code. The application is on SP 2013.

Thanks,

Ankit